# Passing parameters to Stored Procedures in Shared Datasets in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How I can use Stored Procedures in Shared Datasets in SSRS 2016? I want to pass parameters from SSRS.

In Parameters section I don't see my defined parameters.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the parameter values to the datasets embedded in your reports. Those embedded datasets can be pointers to a shared dataset.  This allows you to use different fields or names when passing to a shared dataset from different reports.

If you had to define what to pass within the shared dataset itself, it would take away some of their flexibility, diminishing the reason for even having shared datasets as a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Did you choose the stored procedure from the query section?

Did you create the parameter and datasets?

Visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464.aspx

Comment: I choose procedure in Shared Datasets section. Both parameters and datasets are created.